# Shove installed a launch daemon or agent popup window, what is it?

Tags: security, services, anti-virus, daemons, launch-services

Please check the following screenshot:

[image]

Today, I suddenly have this popup window warning. I have no idea what it is.
Basically I have three questions.

(1) Is this `BlockBlock` app warning? I have no idea how to find which app triggers this warning. Is there a way to find out which app triggers a popup window?

(2) What is this warning about? Does it mean the app `fpsaud` auto installs something?

(3) Should I Block or Allow?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shove appears to be legitimate [Apple software](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7748012) which sometimes triggers virus scanners & whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions in order....

1. This does appear to be a *BlockBlock* dialog box.  A quick look at their [webpage](https://www.objective-see.com/products/blockblock.html) shows a similar dialog to the one you've posted.

[image]

2. This warning is telling you that Adobe is attempting to install/update Adobe Flash Player
3. Do you use Flash Player?  If you do, then yes.  If not, you should investigate what is attempting to install Flash Player (what did you download and open up?)

<sub>*On a side note, a more pragmatic question you should be asking yourself is "Why, in 2018, are you still using Adobe Flash?"</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. (1) Do you know if it's possible and how to check which app owns a window in macos? (2) Why does this popup window say `installed a launch daemon or agent`? To me, the daemon `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.fpsaud.plist` is already there. I think it's just trying to update the flash player app. Why isn't the warning `installing or updating an app`? (3) I am not sure if this flash is the flash plugin for browser. If so, the reason why I need flash in 2018 is because some websites are still using it in my country and my job forces me to use them.

Comment: The popup windows says what it says because they developer coded it that way.   What it's telling you is *something* was written to an area where Agents or Daemons get written to.  A file being updated is a new file being written over the old one; bottom line...a file is being written.

Comment: Also, in the format for this site (Q/A), it's one question per post.  The question about which app owns a window has already been asked and it's important to search to see if what you're looking for has already been asked.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208168/how-can-i-log-all-notifications

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I may ask a new question regarding how to find out which app owns a window if I am really curious later. I think the link you posted is mac notification instead of a window UI, the two are different. But whatever, this is not related to this post as you point out. Thank you very much for your help again.