# Where does launchpad store folder information? (database, etc?)

Tags: macos, folders, launchpad

So i've been searching around and trying to figure this out but can't seem to.

I know that the launchpad SQLite db is stored at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/some-uuid.db` ([ref](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/where-is-the-launchpad-database-stored-and-is-there-a-way-to-edit-it-directly)), but as best I can tell it doesn't seem to include any information about folders created in launchpad.

<s>Does anyone know where this information is stored, and in what format?</s>

**Edit:** Found the location, details in my answer below. The only bits I can't figure out now are:

- How to programatically create a new folder and move apps into it (using this db)
- <s>What the `db-shm` and `db-wal` files are used for.</s>

  - [SQLite temp files](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) (write ahead log & shared memory files)
- Whether `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/some-uuid.db` is used at all anymore, or if it was just leftover from an osx upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think i've found it. Turns out that (at least under El Capitan) things are a little different.

[This AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/how-to-reset-launchpad-ordering-in-os-x-yosemite) by [Greg Hacke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/112442/greg-hacke) pointed me in the right direction.

It seems the databases are stored in `$TMPDIR/../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/`, with the main sqlite db being aptly named `db`.

(After reading [Geoff Hackworth's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/79387/geoff-hackworth) AskDifferent [response](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156832/where-osx-10-10-notification-center-settings-are-stored?rq=1), it seems a better way to get the path would be `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR` rather than `$TMPDIR/../0/`)

Editing this with a sqlite GUI showed that the `groups` table stores the folders, with `title` holding the folder name.

After making any desired changes, and writing them back to the db, we still need to do a `killall Dock` to refresh the launchpad screen.

Some observations:

- There are a number of groups that don't have a `title` (set to null), so not really sure what they are for.
- It seems that just creating a new entry doesn't cause a group to show up (maybe because it would be an 'empty folder'?).

  - In this case, how can we create a new folder and move apps into it from the db?
- By editing the `title` field in the `apps` table we can change the display name of the app.